# How to create a gallery app for usb otg?

Tags: android, image-gallery, usb-otg

I know a library called libaums and had implemented it, but I don't know how to open Images and Videos using their library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://github.com/magnusja/libaums, you can actually read a file from the storage using this:

```
// read from a file
InputStream is = new UsbFileInputStream(file);
byte[] buffer = new byte[currentFs.getChunkSize()];
is.read(buffer);
```

Then your `buffer` contains the image data, so you can convert it to e.g. a Bitmap, like this:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer , 0, buffer .length);
```

After that you can set it to an `ImageView` or whatever to show it to your user.

To be short, find your `File` and implement this logic.

Comment: It worked thanks a lot.
Now I'm done with Images, What about videos ?

Comment: You can read the docs. If it helped for you, please mark this as an answer :)

Comment: Done. Thanks for your help.